# Incorrect argument label in call (have 'with:', expected 'withRegistry:') - flutter_local_notifications iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-local-notification

Hi I do a flutter app which uses flutter_local_notifications library,

I am going alongside with guide (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-ios-setup) to setup IOS notifications

the quide even links to a example code on GitHub https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift

but I got error in AppDelegate file

**Incorrect argument label in call (have 'with:', expected 'withRegistry:')**

[image]

idk what to do, did anyone have that problem?

**replacing "with" by "withRegistry" does not resolve the problem** because then I got error in other way

Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withRegistry:', expected 'with:')

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the same. Though the app does not build when changing it to "withRegistry"

Comment: @James i am not fluent in swift but when I build app not being in that exact file it works somehow, it strange but Xcode catch erorrors when you open that exact file and marks that on red but when you run compilation from different location it compiles just with yellow warnings, my friend who is more into swift and Xcode says that it's related to some background proces with compiling swift -> objective c but idk what that is, it works for me now haha

Answer (score 0):

`cmd + shift + K` to clean

`cmd + b` to build

If still the same issue you can try to update Xcode.